# What is the standard way of computing centroids when you have unknown data?

Tags: python, k-means, centroid

I have to compute the centroid for user ratings. My data is stored in a matrix that looks like this (imagine we have 4 users and 12 ratings):

```
[[0,1,0,-1,0,2,3,4,1,0,0,0],
[0,1,1,-1,0,2,3,4,1,0,2,0],
[0,1,0,0,-1,2,3,4,1,0,0,0],
[0,1,-1,2,0,2,3,4,1,4,-1,-1]]
```

My problem is that I'm not sure what to do with the unknown data, that is, when the user did not rate everything (values initialized to -1 in my example). Right now, 0 means that the user did not like the object at all, 4 means that they loved it. When computing the centroid, what should I do with the values equal to -1? Right now, my code in python looks like this:

```
def calc_centroid(ratMatrix):
  centroid = [0 for x in range(len(ratMatrix[0]))] 
  for i in range(len(ratMatrix)): 
    for j in range(len(ratMatrix[i])):
      centroid[j] = centroid[j] + ratMatrix[i][j]
  count = len(ratMatrix[0])
  for i in range(len(centroid)):
    centroid[i] = centroid[i]*1.0/count;
  return centroid
```

However, I'm not taking into account that "centroid" was calculated using also the -1 values, and I guess that this is not fully correct. What's the standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that centroid is mean average. With 4 ratings of 1, your code returns 0.33. I think it should be 1.

numpy can do a few things that make this make neater.

```
import numpy as np

def calc_centroid(ratMatrix):
  centroid = [0 for x in range(len(ratMatrix[0]))]
  for i in range(len(ratMatrix)):
    for j in range(len(ratMatrix[i])):
      centroid[j] = centroid[j] + ratMatrix[i][j]
  count = len(ratMatrix[0])
  for i in range(len(centroid)):
    centroid[i] = centroid[i]*1.0/count;
  return centroid

def calc_centroid2(ratMatrix):
    mean_ratings = []
    for i in range(ratMatrix.shape[1]): # iterate columns
        col = ratMatrix[:,i]
        col = col[col != -1] #exclude unrated
        mean_ratings.append(np.mean(col))
    return mean_ratings

# 4 users, 12 objects to rate: want the mean rating for each object.
ratMatrix = np.array([[0,1,0 ,-1,0 ,2,3,4,1,0 ,0, 0],
                      [0,1,1 ,-1,0 ,2,3,4,1,0 ,2, 0],
                      [0,1,0 ,0 ,-1,2,3,4,1,0 ,0, 0],
                      [0,1,-1,2 ,0 ,2,3,4,1,4,-1,-1]])

print(ratMatrix)

centroids = calc_centroid(ratMatrix)
print(['{:.2f} '.format(i) for i in centroids])

centroids = calc_centroid2(ratMatrix)
print(['{:.2f} '.format(i) for i in centroids])
```

This yields

```
[[ 0  1  0 -1  0  2  3  4  1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  1 -1  0  2  3  4  1  0  2  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0 -1  2  3  4  1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1 -1  2  0  2  3  4  1  4 -1 -1]]
['0.00 ', '0.33 ', '0.00 ', '0.00 ', '-0.08 ', '0.67 ', '1.00 ', '1.33 ', '0.33 ', '0.33 ', '0.08 ', '-0.08 ']
['0.00 ', '1.00 ', '0.33 ', '1.00 ', '0.00 ', '2.00 ', '3.00 ', '4.00 ', '1.00 ', '1.00 ', '0.67 ', '0.00 ']
```

Comment: I understand. I see why mine was wrong. But then would you ignore also those values when calculating the distance between each of the user ratings and the centroid? I'm not sure how to do that in an easy way, since they won't be zero in the centroid but they will still be in the user rating.

Comment: I think calc_centroid2 in my above answer handles this correctly.